# Validators are not working even with validation group to make sure that update input of custom update button is valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview, updates

I want to be able to `update` the data in the `Gridview` row by `row` and make sure that the data in the `textbox` fields is valid input. However with my code it is checking if the whole page has valid input and is preventing me from making the update changes even if the data in the row that I am trying to update is valid. Also my `label message` is not displaying the `error message` in case of `invalid data`. How can I make it to check that the `row` I am trying to `update` has valid input and if not output the `error message`?
Here is my HTML code:

```html
<br />
<asp:Label ID="MessageLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br />


<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Editing Table"></asp:Label>


<br />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="GridView4_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView4_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton OnClick="UpdateRow_Click" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="UpdateGCommand" Text="Update">
        </asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'>
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="UpdatingGrid" ID="rfvName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name is a required field" ControlToValidate="textBox1" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Email")%>'>
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="UpdatingGrid" ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email is a required field" ControlToValidate="textBox2" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationGroup="UpdatingGrid" ID="RegularExpressionValidatorEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Invalid Email" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="textBox2" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Mobile")%>'>
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="UpdatingGrid" ID="rfvMobile" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Mobile is a required field" ControlToValidate="textBox3" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


  </Columns>
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is my c# code:

```js
  protected void GridView4_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == "UpdateGCommand") {
      if (IsPostBack) {

        Page.Validate("UpdatingGrid");
        while (!Page.IsValid) {
          if (Page.IsValid) {

            DataSet EditT = new DataSet();
            DataSet ValidT = new DataSet();
            DataRow row;
            if (Session["Edit"] != null) {
              EditT = (DataSet) Session["Edit"];
            }
            if (Session["Valid"] != null) {
              ValidT = (DataSet) Session["Valid"];
            }

            DataTable dtEdit = EditT.Tables[0];
            DataTable dtValid = ValidT.Tables[0];



            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton) e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
            row = dtEdit.Rows[RowIndex];
            string txtName = ((TextBox) GridView4.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("textBox1")).Text;
            string txtEmail = ((TextBox) GridView4.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("textBox2")).Text;
            string txtMobile = ((TextBox) GridView4.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("textBox3")).Text;

            if (txtName != null) {
              EditT.Tables[0].Rows[RowIndex]["Name"] = txtName;
            }


            if (txtEmail != null) {
              EditT.Tables[0].Rows[RowIndex]["Email"] = txtEmail;
            }

            if (txtMobile != null) {
              EditT.Tables[0].Rows[RowIndex]["Mobile"] = txtMobile;
            }
            dtValid.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
            dtEdit.Rows[RowIndex].Delete();
            GridView4.DataSource = EditT;
            GridView5.DataSource = ValidT;
            GridView4.DataBind();
            GridView5.DataBind();
          } else {
            MessageLbl.Text = "Invalid Input";
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the

> ValidationGroup

attribute to your linkbutton as well.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="yourId" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="UpdatingGrid" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure even if putting `ValidationGroup` attribute on your buttons will work or not as all the rows will have same validation group for their controls. You can try making validation group unique to each row like by putting this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
 ValidationGroup="<%# String.Format("UpdatingGrid{0}", Container.DataItemIndex)%>" ...>
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

and also on button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup="<%# String.Format("UpdatingGrid{0}", Container.DataItemIndex)%>"
```

if this does not work then you can tap good old `RowCreated` event (or `RowDataBound` as well):

```
GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
    if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
        return;

    var rfem = e.Row.FindControl("rfvEmail") as RequiredFieldValidator;
    if(rfem!=null){
        rfem.ValidationGroup = "UpdatingGrid" + e.Row.RowIndex;
    }
    //do same for other validators and button as well.
}
```